# Learning Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm PHP developer working on it since 2 years. I have worked on C#.NET before PHP but then I moved to PHP and now i am working in PHP world. I have good experience of WordPress development and i am quick learner with solid object orient programing.

Nowadays, I really want to learn some other existing programming languages. I'm keen to learn Ruby on Rails because i can see, it is growing day by day.

1. Can anybody tell me about my this decision?
2. Is Ruby on Rails framework provides all the feature like other do?
3. Will the Ruby on Rails will be prominent in coming years?
4. Will i be able to earn my good living?

I don't totally want to move on Ruby on Rails, I'll keep working on PHP but Ruby sounds me great. Thanks

Comment: This is not the forum for these types of questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: And the correct one is: http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ruby is one of the funniest language out there but Rails can be such a pain if bad used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also rails developer and I started on PHP. But, Rails are great!
According to your questions, I think the answers are YES. Just see how many companies are seeking for Rails developer.

Great tutorials you can find here:

[RailsCasts.com](http://railscasts.com) by Ryan Bates

http://railsapps.github.com/ - also great source for learning

Answer (score 1):

I am a Rails developer, and I found that Rails is very great at building web application as well as web services. Working with Rails I could get 50% of my work done. Anyway, there is a great website for getting start with Rails. You can spend sometime with it if you want: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with PHP but start easing into RoR then you might look into CakePHP. I started MVC with CakePHP and it was an easy transition into RoR. Now I know both and got some great experience.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

## YES.

1. Your decision is good.
2. RoR has everything you could need.
3. ## YES.
4. My Magic 8 Ball says:

   ## YES.

---

## [RailsTutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)

by *Michael Hartl* is all you need.